# Files organization Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, cakephp

I am starting a migration project from cakephp 2 to Symfony 3. I am trying to find the best organization for the different functions for my code.
In cakephp I have very simple organization: I used model, view and controller. On this point no problem with Symfony (same organization). But I also have 5 php libraries with only one or two function in each, and 3 object classes not linked to database. In cakephp all this files are in the Lib folder.
Where can I create and use this libraries and classes in Symfony (not in a new bundle)?

Comment: Their demo might help: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-demo/tree/master/src
if possible use composer for external dependencies, else put it into the `src/AppBundle` folder

Comment: Nothing wrong with having a src/Lib folder in your project to get started.  Later, if you need to share these functions across multiple projects then you can move them into their own composer package.  But keep it simple for now.